# How to animate multiple progress bars at the same time?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, progress-bar

I need to make a progress bar for the different elements in my data base. I have currently 4 items in my database and each of them will have a progress bar associated.
I'm using ASP.Net Core (MVC) where I have a class called Server with two attributes: ComputerName and Type.

Here is the html code to create multiple progress bars:

```
 <div class="container">
<h2>Patch Management Progress</h2>
@foreach (var server in Model)
{
    <div id="serverName">@server.ComputerName</div>
    <div class="progress">
        <div id="myProgress" class="bar bar-danger"></div>

    </div>
}

</div>
```

Here is the javascript code:

$('.progress').each(function () {

```
var bar = document.getElementById("myProgress");
var progress = 0;


function setProgress(percent) {
    bar.style.width = percent + "%";

    if (percent < 30) {
        bar.className = "progress-bar progress-bar-danger progress-bar-striped active";
    } else if (percent >= 30 && percent < 70) {
        bar.className = "progress-bar progress-bar-warning progress-bar-striped active";
    } else if (percent >= 70 && percent < 80) {
        bar.className = "progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped active";
    } else if (percent >= 80 && percent < 100) {
        bar.className = "progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped active";
    } else if (percent == 100) {
        bar.className = "progress-bar progress-bar-success";
    }


}

var interval = setInterval(
    function () {
        setProgress(++progress);
        if (progress == 100) window.clearInterval(interval);
    }, 100);


});
```

Note: Right now I'm not worried about the percentage of each progress bar, I just want to make sure all of them are animated

Here is the output:

[image]

Only one of them is animated. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id`s must be unique. Instead, give each progress bar a class and select it with `querySelector`.

HTML:

```html
 <div class="container">
<h2>Patch Management Progress</h2>
@foreach (var server in Model)
{
    <div class="serverName">@server.ComputerName</div>
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="myProgress bar bar-danger"></div>

    </div>
}

</div>
```

JS:

```js
$('.progress').each(function () {

var bar = this.querySelector(".myProgress");
var progress = 0;


function setProgress(percent) {
    bar.style.width = percent + "%";

    if (percent < 30) {
        bar.className = "myProgress progress-bar progress-bar-danger progress-bar-striped active";
    } else if (percent >= 30 && percent < 70) {
        bar.className = "myProgress progress-bar progress-bar-warning progress-bar-striped active";
    } else if (percent >= 70 && percent < 80) {
        bar.className = "myProgress progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped active";
    } else if (percent >= 80 && percent < 100) {
        bar.className = "myProgress progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped active";
    } else if (percent == 100) {
        bar.className = "myProgress progress-bar progress-bar-success";
    }


}

var interval = setInterval(
    function () {
        setProgress(++progress);
        if (progress == 100) window.clearInterval(interval);
    }, 100);


});
```

Comment: It does not seem to be working still. And I don't think a div can have two class attributes

Comment: @Sam didn't notice that. I've updated my answer. It should work now.

Comment: It works now! Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @Sam no problem :)